# Light reflexion mitigation with findCountours() using OpenCV?

Tags: java, image, opencv, contour

I'm quite new to OpenCV but after some hours working on it, I'm beggining to understand its workings. I'm working on a leaf recognition functionality using OpenCV-2.4.11 in Java but there are some problems because of light reflexion. 
Here is the original image:[image: original leaf image]

I've applied some transformations on it to get the contours but the light reflexion is causing problems.
I used the commands below:

```
Imgproc.cvtColor(dst, dst, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
Imgproc.threshold(dst, dst, 0, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY_INV + Imgproc.THRESH_OTSU);
```

and it produced the following result:[image]

Now, since I'm interested on the contours, I applied

```
ArrayList<MatOfPoint> points = new ArrayList<>();
Imgproc.findContours(dst, points, new Mat(), Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
Imgproc.drawContours(dst, points, -1, new Scalar(255, 0, 0), 1);
```

and it gave me[image]

The defects are caused by the light reflexion and I don't know how to deal with it.

I tried using HLS colorspace reducing the L channel values (of the original image) to 60% of its original values, so the image became like this:
[image]

Over that, I ran the following commands`

```
Imgproc.cvtColor(dst, dst, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
Imgproc.threshold(dst, dst, 0, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY_INV + Imgproc.THRESH_OTSU);
ArrayList<MatOfPoint> points = new ArrayList<>();
Imgproc.findContours(dst, points, new Mat(), Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
Imgproc.drawContours(dst, points, -1, new Scalar(255, 0, 0), 1);
```

Resulting in[image]

Since I don't have much knowledge of OpenCV or Image processing, I'm stuck on this issue.

Does anyone know how to solve (or mitigate) this problem?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can't you take the picture without camera flash?

Comment: @Miki yes, but since I want to make it a tool for the community, I'd like to make it as robust as possible.

Answer (score 1):

my trial code based on [HoughLinesP](http://docs.opencv.org/master/dd/d1a/group__imgproc__feature.html#ga8618180a5948286384e3b7ca02f6feeb&gsc.tab=0) is below. i hope it helps.

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

    int main(int argc, char** argv)
    {
        Mat src, src_gray, edges;

        char* filename = argc >= 2 ? argv[1] : (char*)"ibqYp.jpg";
        src = imread( filename, 1 );

        if( src.empty() )
        {
            return -1;
        }

        cvtColor( src, src_gray, COLOR_RGB2GRAY );
        Canny( src_gray, edges, 50, 200, 3 );

        vector<Vec4i> p_lines;

        HoughLinesP( edges, p_lines, 1, CV_PI/180, 50, 30, 10 );

        for( size_t i = 0; i < p_lines.size(); i++ )
        {
            Vec4i l = p_lines[i];
            if( abs(l[2]-l[0]) > abs(l[3]-l[1])* 3 ) // this is for filter vertical lines
                line( src, Point(l[0], l[1]), Point(l[2], l[3]), Scalar(0,255,0), 1, LINE_AA);
        }
         cvtColor( src, src_gray, COLOR_RGB2GRAY );
         src_gray = src_gray < 190;
        imshow("result", src_gray );
        waitKey(0);
        return 0;
    }
```

Result image ( you can find the external contours easily )

[image]